# Drupal : How to change or where I can find username line for comments view in the script?

Tags: drupal, drupal-comments

In Drupal display comments box I want to change the display username to first and last name. I have already setup the database and I know I can user `$user->name` to find the first and last name in my separate database table.

But my problem is, in the script where I should change it? I have looked in the comments module but I am not sure that script for viewing the comments.

Please can you tell me in which place I can find the displaying username in the comments view box in the script.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried this but no success... <?php print theme('username', array('account' => $content['comment_body']['#object'])) ?><?php print render($content) ?>

Comment: Please someone tell me where I can find  $content['comment_body']['#object'] array?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to display the Firstname + Lastname of the comment author instead of the username while displaying the comments? If that is the case, then you can easily do that in your comment.tpl.php file instead of editing the comment module.

Comment: I looked in that file but I didn't understand where I can edit?? please take a look and help me... link : http://pastebin.com/JDN9tfDR

Comment: I think I need help over here. How can convert this :  `print theme('username', array('account' => $content['comment_body']['#object']))` to a string? please @Abhijit help me....

Comment: Sorry I was not able to answer. Hope you already found a solution. There can be many ways to print the firstname+lastname in place of the username. The easiest of them is to use the $comment object (unless that is not available in your comment.tpl for some reason). You can do a `$user = user_load($comment->uid)`. Now you can use the `$user` object to print the firstname and lastname if they are fields i.e. `print $user->field_firstname['und'][0]['value']` (there are better methods like using field_get_items). Hope you are getting the idea.

Comment: Thank-you thank-you so much Abhijit.. You solved my problem...... Now I can access the $user. This is what I want... thanks...